# Using standard notation for vector magnitude

Tags: vector, notation

The mathematical notation for the magnitude of a vector is $\vert x \vert$, but this does not work:

```
∥ {1, 2, 3} ∥
```

Is there any way to overload the `DoubleVerticalBar` symbol so my Mathematica code would look like a textbook formula?

Comment: Please try `Norm`.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I know about `Norm`, but I would like to use a "nicer" notation for it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only want to have the "nice" format for input, you could assign `Norm` to `DoubleBracketingBar` (which is equivalent to `\[LeftDoubleBracketingBar] # \[RightDoubleBracketingBar] &`)

```
DoubleBracketingBar := Norm
DoubleBracketingBar[x]
(* Norm[x] *)
```

Alternatively, and more usable, you could use the `Notation` package

```
Needs["Notation`"]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"DoubleBracketingBar", "[", "x_", 
     "]"}]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"Norm", "[", "x_", "]"}]]]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"\[LeftDoubleBracketingBar]", "x_", 
     "\[RightDoubleBracketingBar]"}]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] 
  ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"Norm", "[", "x_", "]"}]]]
```

Which is displayed more readable as

[image: The way the input is displayed in the notebook]

The usage is then as expected:

```
DoubleBracketingBar[x] // FullForm
(* Norm[x] *)
\[LeftDoubleBracketingBar]x\[RightDoubleBracketingBar] \
// FullForm
(* Norm[x] *)
Norm[x]
(* \[LeftDoubleBracketingBar]x\[RightDoubleBracketingBar] *)
```

**Edit**: By the way, the reason I did not use `\[DoubleVerticalBar]` is because it is built in as an infix operator.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Do you happen to know an easy way to insert the special character for `DoubleBracketingBar` aswell? It isn't in the `Esc` menu

Comment: @lama12345 `Esc-l||-Esc` and `Esc-r||-Esc` (left and right double bar) works.

Answer (score 5):

You could create an input alias for this:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases, "norm"}] = TemplateBox[
    {"\[SelectionPlaceholder]"},
    "Norm"
]
```

The only downside is you have to tab to the placeholder.

Comment: Wow, `Norm` with `DoubleBracketingBar` feels like a native construct now (at least for one notebook). Thank you a lot!